# Does Bluemix include a JBoss runtime?

Tags: jboss, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

How can I create a JBoss runtime on Bluemix?

The [JBoss buildpack for Cloud Foundry](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jboss-buildpack) does not support all features. The current buildpack is focused on running web applications in the servlet container and nothing further.

Are there more docs on this and any updates on the plans going forward, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really two questions:

1. The JBoss buildpack for Cloud Foundry only runs servlets.
2. How do I create a JBoss runtime on Bluemix?

I'll let the Cloud Foundry and JBoss communities address the usefulness of that buildpack. Bluemix lets you upload Cloud Foundry buildpacks, so you could use this in Bluemix to create a JBoss runtime.

You might think of the second question this way:

1. How do I deploy my JBoss application on Bluemix?

The Java runtime that's built into Bluemix is the [Liberty for Java](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html) runtime. It supports the Java EE6 Web Profile plus many Java EE 7 technologies, as explained in [Programming model support](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support.html). This mans that as long as your JBoss app is Java EE compliant and doesn't use relatively exotic features, it should run just fine in Liberty.

If you want to deploy your app on Bluemix but want to run it in JBoss instead of Liberty (bearing in mind that IBM supports the Liberty runtime, but can't be responsible for ones you create yourself), you have a couple of options. In order of preference:

1. Use a Cloud Foundry buildpack for JBoss
2. Deploy a Docker container with the JBoss runtime installed
3. Deploy a VM with the JBoss runtime installed

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix out of the box doesn't include a JBoss buildpack. It includes WAS Liberty one to run Java SE and Java EE apps: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

I understand you are referring to the Cloudfoundry JBoss buildpack, aren't you? Which in fact can also be used in Bluemix as a custom buildpack. In taht case, all its documentation, roadmap and discussions around it can be found in its Git Repository at: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jboss-buildpack